# Install Jira: issue with java JDK

Tags: java

I am trying to install Jira which requires java JDK.
I installed the latest Java JDK and it says it was successfully installed.
However I get an error:

```
Unable to locate an executable at “/usr/bin/java/bin/java” (-1)
```

when I try to install Jira (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873437/unable-to-locate-an-executable-at-usr-bin-java-bin-java-1))

the answers to that question do not work for me (setting `JAVA_HOME`), so what exactly should I do?

- which version of JDK did you install, from where?

  - latest and from oracle
- What does file /usr/bin/java return (and if it is a symlink, where does it point to)?

  - `/usr/bin/java: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures:[x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [i386:Mach-O executable i386] /usr/bin/java (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64 /usr/bin/java (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386`
- What is in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

  - `A/`, `Current/`
- What is in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/

  - `Commands/`, `JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/`, `Resources/`, `Frameworks/`, `JavaVM_CodeSignature/`, `Headers/`, `Modules/`
- What is in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

  - `jdk`

Comment: Please include the error you get directly in your question. Also: where is your Java installed? Can you run `java` from the commandline? How do you install Jira?

Comment: @patrix error is same as in linked S.E. question, /usr/bin/java, running java yields Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java" (-1), I have tried via command line and via zip

Comment: Please make the question stand on its own. Having people clicking a link to just understand the problem will decrease the chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Also: which version of JDK did you install, from where? What does `file /usr/bin/java` return (and if it is a symlink, where does it point to)? What is in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`,  `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/`, `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/java: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures:[x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [i386:Mach-O executable i386] /usr/bin/java (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64 /usr/bin/java (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386` and `A/, Current/`; `Commands/, JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/, Resources/, Frameworks/, JavaVM_CodeSignature/, Headers/, Modules/`; and `jdk`